# how do I remove the number labels on the bars of a primeng bar graph?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to remove the numbers on the bar graphs. I'm not sure what to change on the Options array to make this happen. Here is my graph.

https://ibb.co/G7nR3mz

and here is my Options array

```js
 this.Options = {
      legend: {
          labels: {
              fontColor: '#495057'
          }
      },
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  fontColor:'#495057'
              },
              gridLines: {
                  display: false
              }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  fontColor:'#495057',
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 80
              }
          }]
      }
  };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone runs into this in the future:

the options json has an these settings that can be used to remove the numbers

```
this.options = {
series: [ {
type: 'bar', 
xkey: 'step',
fills: [ '#2ced11'],
strokes: ['#2ced11'],
}
],
axes [ {
type: 'number', 
label: {
formatter: (formatParam): string => Replace_this_with_your_settings
}
]

}
```